# getting error as 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when one list is not showing any error

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am new to Python. I separated lists into two other lists with one having starting n elements and the other list having the ending n elements.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n=3
res = list[-n:]
list_i=[]
list_j=[]
for i in range (0,n):
    list_i.append(list[i])
    print(list_i)
for j in range(0,res):
    list_j.append(res[j])
    print(list_j)
```

I tried to use the same for loop for the list_j but it gives TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I am not clear as the type for list and res both are <class 'list'>

Comment: Be careful when deciding on variable names. It's rarely a good idea to use variable names such as *list* because that's a built-in function. You will override/shadow it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first loop, you iterate from 0 to 3.
In the second loop, you are iterating from 0 to res. res is a list with values [6, 7, 8].

The error is saying the following: A list is not an integer. Your stop value MUST be a integer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. Your few words gave me the answer I wanted. It seems to be a silly question now.

Answer (score 0):

my_list[:n] returns a sublist containing the first n elements of my_list and assigns it to list_i.
my_list[-n:] returns a sublist containing the last n elements of my_list and assigns it to list_j.
Finally, we print both list_i and list_j.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
n = 3

list_i = my_list[:n]
list_j = my_list[-n:]

print(list_i)
print(list_j)
```

my_list[:n] represents slicing from the beginning of my_list up to index n. It returns a new list containing the first n elements of my_list. The index n is not inclusive, so it stops at the element at index n-1. In other words, it extracts elements from index 0 to index n-1.

my_list[-n:] represents slicing from index -n to the end of my_list. Negative indices count from the end of the list, so -1 refers to the last element, -2 refers to the second-last element, and so on. This slicing operation returns a new list containing the last n elements of my_list.

Comment: Thank you. I could implement it in this way also. Seems more neat.

Comment: I am sorry I accidentally did that. Kinda new to this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't call your variable list. List is already a built-in class in python, so when you name your list as list, you overwrite it.

In your loop, you're passing a list as the second argument to the range function. If you wanted to do it that way, you need to pass the length of the list instead.

```
for j in range(0, len(res)):
    list_j.append(res[j])
    print(list_j)
```

But that is not good python code.

A list already has a built in interator, so if you just want the numbers in the list, it's sufficient to write:

```
for j in res:
   list_j.append(j)
   print(list_j)
```

Note that you also don't need to reference the list inside the loop. Python returns the actual value, not the index.

If you needed to use the index for something as well, and not just the value, the better way would be:

```
for index, value in enumerate(res):
    print(index)
    print(value)
```